# Boot delay due to touchpad

Tags: boot, lubuntu, touchpad, acer

After I changed my Notebook's processor from T4500 to T9300, the Lubuntu 20.04 delays at boot-up due to the two last lines I marked in the photo. At first it looses ~8 sec. on PS/2 touchpad, then ~ 8 sec. on ata1 device. This problem happens not every time, but mostly when I reboot the system. At the cold startup most of the time the problem doesn't appear.

What could be the problem?
Notebook model: Acer Extensa 5635z
[image]

Comment: Does this system also have Windows installed? If so, does the issue appear when you "reboot" from Windows into Lubuntu?

Comment: No, I have only Lubuntu installed, Crucial 256GB SSD. Sometimes it immediately boots when after hanging on touchpad line I start to press some random keys